# Can I change the current date and time for a specific process?

Tags: unit-testing, time, mocking

Is there a way to change the date and time seen by a specific process as opposed to the entire computer (i.e. the time returned by `time()` in C, by `DateTime.Now` in C#, by `datetime.now()` in Python, by `new Date()` in JavaScript, by `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Java, etc.)?

For instance, is there a way to fool a program into thinking it's midnight while it's 7 AM on the rest of the computer, or to make it think it's Christmas or Leap Day while the system clock shows July 18th?

An applicable situation would be when you're writing unit tests and you want to quickly test any special behavior the program has on Christmas or on Leap Day or on the demo's expiration date, and you want to test this behavior without having to use the date changing function in the OS and interfere with programs that rely on the date being correct (much less forcing me to have superuser privileges over the computer).

Comment: @Erik I would probably write a time interface if I needed it at another time, such as if I was writing a game that wanted to distinguish between game time and real time or was using time manipulation. However, I wonder if there's a way to configure the single-point interface that the language already provides so that it doesn't have to be modified in those situations where it's difficult or impossible to change the functionality (such as when a closed-source library calls `time()`).

Comment: @Erik You can go ahead and put that as an answer - it *is* a solution to my problem. The ideal solution I'm looking for, however, is changing the system time from the OS for an entire, specifc process and only that process - not modifying `DateTime.Now`, but the value returned by the *syscall* that it makes, *before* it makes it. This prevents me from having to rewrite code just to test its timing behavior.

Answer (score 3):

Previously mentioned Typemock also has an [API](https://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) for C++, which also allows you to fake time, in C++:

```
TEST_METHOD(FakeCurrentTime)
{
    SYSTEMTIME fakeTime;
    fakeTime.wYear = 2000;
    fakeTime.wMonth = 1;
    fakeTime.wDay = 1;

    FAKE_GLOBAL(GetSystemTime);
    WHEN_CALLED(GetSystemTime(RET(&fakeTime))).Ignore();

    SYSTEMTIME now;
    GetSystemTime(&now);

    Assert::IsTrue(now.wMilliseconds - fakeTime.wMilliseconds == 0);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do what you want to do in C#. There aren't any hooks that I know of to make `DateTime.Now` return arbitrary values out of the box. The standard way to implement unit testing that is time sensitive is to create a time provider interface. This is the approach taken by third party libraries such as [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/1.2.x/userguide/testing.html) that values testing time related functions. One such implementation is below (not Noda Time compatible):

```cs
public ITimeProvider
{
    DateTime CurrentTime { get; }
    DateTime CurrentUtcTime { get; }
}

public DefaultTimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{
    public DateTime CurrentTime { get { return DateTime.Now; } }
    public DateTime CurrentUtcTime { get { return DateTime.UtcNow; } }
}
```

Then when you want to unit test the code you replace the `DefaultTimeProvider` implementation with a mock implementation. You can use your favorite mocking framework or just write something like this:

```cs
public MockTimeProvider : ITimeProvider
{
    private readonly DateTime _currentTime;
    private readonly DateTime _currentUtcTime;

    public MockTimeProvider(DateTime currentTime, DateTime currentUtcTime)
    {
        _currentTime = currentTime;
        _currentUtcTime = currentUtcTime;
    }

    public DateTime CurrentTime { get { return _currentTime; } }
    public DateTime CurrentUtcTime { get { return _currentUtcTime; } }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Disclaimer, I work at Typemock.

You can use [Typemock Isolator](http://www.typemock.com) for this:

```
[TestMethod]
public void isLicenseExpiredTest()
{
    Isolate.WhenCalled(() => DateTime.Now).WillReturn(new DateTime(2017, 5, 4));

    bool result = Licenses.IsLicenseExpired();

    Assert.IsFalse(result);
}

public static class Licenses
{
    public static bool IsLicenseExpired()
    {

        if (DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2016, 5, 4))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is an amazing tool. http://www.typemock.com/TypemockIsolatorExamples#staticMethod is basically the same as your example. They add the `Isolated` attribute to the test method. Is that required?

Comment: [Isolated] automatically cleans the setup of a test to prevent it from leaking to other tests. This way each test runs in an Isolated environment and the tests don't effect each other. The only exception is static constructors which are called only once by the CLR and sometimes you want them to be invoked once per test, but we have a solution for this as well :)

Answer (score 1):

## java.time

Java 8 and later has the java.time framework built in. Supplants the old date-time classes.

### `Clock`

Includes the [`Clock`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Clock.html) class. You can override this class to make your own faked current time.

A few alternate implementations are included via static methods. You can ask for a `Clock` that stays fixed on a single moment you specify. You can shift the current time by some specified amount. And you have the Clock report the current moment rounded to the whole second or minute and so on.